# Javascript Add Date Problem

Tags: javascript, date

I've this snippet:

```
var d1 = parseInt( document.getElementById('day1').value );
var m1 = parseInt( document.getElementById('month1').value );
var y1 = parseInt( document.getElementById('year1').value );

var dt = new Date();
dt.setYear(y1);
dt.setMonth(m1);
dt.setDate(d1 + 1);

document.getElementById('day2').value = dt.getDate();
document.getElementById('month2').value = dt.getMonth();
document.getElementById('year2').value = dt.getYear();
```

My goal is, to automatically init value of date2 by adding 1 day from date1.
However, when I fill :

```
 day1 = 32
 month1 = 1
 year1 = 2009
```

I got :

```
 day1 = 5
 month1 = 2
 year1 = 2009
```

I don't know what is going on. Do you guys know the solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects/Date_Object) object handles months as zero-based numbers (0-Jan,1-Feb,...,11-Dec).

Also you can have [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251941) with the `set` methods, I would recommend you to use the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date):

```
var d1 = +document.getElementById('day1').value;
var m1 = +document.getElementById('month1').value - 1; // zero based!!
var y1 = +document.getElementById('year1').value;

var dt = new Date(y1, m1, d1);
```

Comment: can you tell me more, what problem would that be?

Answer (score 1):

See The [Add Days To A JavaScript Date](http://www.rodsdot.com/javascript/add-days-to-javascript-date.asp) example.

Comment: Sadly this does not work. It does not account correctly for days which are longer or shorter than 24 hours (the leap year days). For example, on the script at this site, try this date: 7/11/2010 (November, 7 2010) while in the eastern time zone.